# How to set the number of cards in a row in a card-group in Bootstrap 5?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

how to set the number of cards in a row in a card-group in Bootstrap 5? I need to have no more than 5 cards in a row. How to do it?

Comment: Try wrapping 5 cards with a col-12. you might run into resizing issues tho. I think the cards size doesnt change (not sure!).

Ex: <div class=Container> <div class=Row> <div class=Col> "5 cards"

Answer (score 0):

```xml
    <div class="container"
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col">
                Insert card 1 here
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Insert card 2 here
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Insert card 3 here
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Insert card 4 here
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                Insert card 5 here
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Likewise adjust the class col as you want. Remove one class col if you want 4 cards to be displayed.